# iOS: How to play buffering audio in bluetooth headset in my music app?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, bluetooth, airplay

I am currently doing one music app. in that i need to play buffering
 audio song in blue tooth headset. i searched for code past 1 day. but
 i can't. please give solution how to add this in my music app.

One more thing i need to play that audio in bluetooth headset while iphone is in backeground mode and screen lock mode.

```
   AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
//[audioSession setDelegate:self];
NSError *error;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];


// check the audio route
UInt32 size = sizeof(CFStringRef);
CFStringRef route;

OSStatus result = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &size, &route);
NSLog(@"route = %@", route);
// if bluetooth headset connected, should be "HeadsetBT"
// if not connected, will be "ReceiverAndMicrophone"

// now, play a quick sound we put in the bundle (bomb.wav)
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef        soundFileURLRef;
SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;
soundFileURLRef  = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle,CFSTR ("sample"),CFSTR ("m4a"),NULL);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);     // should play into headset
```

I have added this code in my music app. but this code is for Bundle audio file. but i need buffering audio. if it is not possible please tell is my code is correcte to play local audio file through blue tooth headset.?

Comment: Please post anything that you've tried, even if it's a non-buffering thing that plays to Bluetooth, or a buffering thing that doesn't play to Bluetooth.  Post whatever you've got.

Comment: BTW You can find sample files on http://techslides.com/sample-files-for-development

Comment: @raja have you added permission about play audio background mode in info.plist ?

Answer (score 0):

From what i read in the documentation , setting the category for the audio session  should be

> AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord

or

> AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord

if setting the option to

```
 AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
```

so you should change that, another thing when i look at the enum: `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions`  the option to bluetooth is `__TVOS_PROHIBITED` but i don't know the alternative...